# VBS using an array to paste data in columns sequentially

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a code in VBA for excel. That reads a folder copies all the data from the .csv worksheets in Excel  inside a folder and pastes it to one worksheet sequentially. But I can't get the array to Paste in sequential order starting with A and going B column then C column etc. instead it is starting in B and going C column, D column etc. each separate .csv worksheets has to be in its own separate column. I'm mainly talking about the array part that copies and pastes the data. Hopes that clears things up.

```
'----------------copy and paste loop begins/storing not .csv files---------------------

For Each oFile In MyFSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder).Files

Dim lastRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim CurrentFileColumn As Long

Dim lastUsedColumn As Long

    If LCase(Right(oFile.Name, 4)) = ".csv" Then

        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path, , Format:=5)

        lastUsedColumn = DestinationWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, DestinationWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        CurrentFileColumn = IIf(lastUsedColumn >= 0, lastUsedColumn + 1, 1)

        For Each ws In Wb.Sheets

        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        dataArray = ws.Range("A1:Z" & lastRow).Value

        DestinationWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, CurrentFileColumn).Resize(UBound(dataArray, 1), UBound(dataArray, 2)).Value = dataArray

        CurrentFileColumn = CurrentFileColumn + UBound(dataArray, 2) + 1
```

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but why `For Each ws In Wb.Sheets`? Wb is `Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path, , Format:=5)` and oFile must be a csv `If LCase(Right(oFile.Name, 4)) = ".csv" Then`. csv file can't have sheets, can they?

Comment: Why do you ask (in words) about something and then you show **a lot of code having nothing to do with the question explanation**? At least, mentioning the code line which behaves in that specific way **against your wish, which means ...**. Are you talking about `dataArray`? If so, your code pastes **on the first row, starting from the column after `lastUsedColumn`**. Isn't that what you want? If not, what are you **specifically** talking about? We are not mind readers, that's why you should explain **in words** what you need against **specific code lines do**...

Comment: If will only paste in columns A,B,C,D sequentially if all the csv files have only one column of data, is that what you have ?

Comment: `lastUsedColumn` will be 1 (col A) for an empty sheet so `IIf(lastUsedColumn >= 0, lastUsedColumn + 1, 1)` will return 2 starting first file in column B.